# Help me to Improve my method of creating a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Based on a past exam question:

Q:Consider the matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{5&-6&0\\4&-5&0\\-1&1&2}$$

with entries from $\mathbb{C}$. Find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{−1}AP = D$.

> A: My attempt was as follows
>
> Using the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(\lambda)= 0$. I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda= 2, -1, 1$. All of multiplicity = $1$.
>
> Next use the formula $(\lambda I_n - A)$ and find the basis of the $U_\lambda$ eigenspace for each $\lambda= 2, -1, 1$.
>
> This is done by performing the calculation $(\lambda I_n - A) = A'$, reducing A' by elemenry row operations, and then finding a vector $U=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ such that using the $A'*U=0$.
>
> I found this to be:
>
> "the basis of $U_2$ is $\left\lbrace \pmatrix{0\\0\\1} \right\rbrace$"
>
> "the basis of $U_{-1} is \left\lbrace \pmatrix{0\\0\\0} \right\rbrace$"
>
> "the basis of $U_{1} is \left\lbrace \pmatrix{-1/2\\1/2\\1} \right\rbrace$"
>
> Since unless stated otherwise, we are working with the standard basis, hence the transition matrix is
>
> $$P = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1/2&1/2&1}$$
>
> $P^-1$ can be found by the forumal $${1/det(P)} * Cof(P)^T$$
>
> Where the $det(P)$ = the determinant of $p$, and $cof(P)^T$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix
>
> However I found the $det(P)=0$ meaning by the formula, $0=D$, and the diagonal matrix does not exist?

I assume my method to find Eigenvectors are at fault, I ask for advise on how to properly find the basis of the eigenspaces or the eigenvectors, and what the true answer is.

Comment: how could possibly be the $0$-vector an eigenvector?

Comment: I didn't know, I apologies if I offended you, (I clearly offended someone since they marked me down), that's why I asked this question, linear algebra is not my strong suite, I'm more of an applied mathematician.

Comment: Don't worry, you didn't offend me. Not sure why someone would downvote your question though...anyway, my comment was more like "this can't be right, check it again". The $0$ vector is by definition no eigenvector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the eigenvector is never (0,0,0)...

$U_{-1}\cdots\\
(A-(-1)I)U_{-1} =0\\ \begin{bmatrix}6&-6&0\\4&-4&0\\-1&1&3\end{bmatrix}U_{-1}=0\\
$

$U_{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$U_1\cdots\\
(A-I)U_1 =0\\ \begin{bmatrix}4&-6&0\\4&-6&0\\-1&1&1\end{bmatrix}U_1=0\\
$

$U_1=\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: so do you not need to row reduce you matrix before we can find our Eigen vectors? The method our professor gave us was based around reducing the matrix, finding the number of "leading 1's" which would give you $V = (v_1, v_2, 1)^T$ and then you find the remaining $v_1 and v_2$ by the formula you have shown. Is this a correct method, or would you recommend finding the U vector directly?

Comment: Almost always I find the the vectors directly.  By the way, on your comment above, linear algebra is ripe with applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check your working, it is very easy to make a mistake with diagonal matrices, you never have a zero eigenvector